# How to call a method from another class with no constructor

Tags: java

I'm having a bit of trouble on a program at school.

I have to call a method called `factorial` in my `FactorialCalculator` class through a method called `factorial` in my `BCD` class. Normally, I would do something like this:

```
FactorialCalculator newCalc = new FactorialCalculator(8);
```

However, `factorial` is the only method in the `FactorialCalculator` class, and I am not allowed to make any more methods, including a constructor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: While making it static is best, note that if you don't define a constructor, you get a default constructor for free.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create it as a **static** method:

```
public class FactorialCalculator {
    public static int factorial(int number) {
        // Calculate factorial of number
    }
}
```

And you can call it this way:

```
int factorial = FactorialCalculator.factorial(5); // for the example
```

A **static** method is a method that is not associated with any instance of any class, & it can be accessed using the **Classname.staticMethod( )** notation.

Answer (score 4):

It's Simple, if you make it `Static`, You will be able to call it from another class.
Create it as a static method:

```
class FactorialCalculator {
    public static int factorial(int number) {
        ...YourCode...
    }
}
```

And you can call it this way:

```
int number = 10;
int f = FactorialCalculator.factorial(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a static method, you would do `FactorialCalculator.factorial(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a default constructor, which is just `FactorialCalculator fc = new FactorialCalculator();`. Easy as that. However, it looks like your teacher wants you to create a static method. Static methods are sort of like utilities of a class, instead of being a function of an object. So, in your case, you should make FactorialCalculator be more of a utility class instead of an object class. `public static int factorial(int num) {}` should do the trick. This way, you can just go `FactorialCalculator.factorial(5)` as you did in your example.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

First, you always have the standard constructor, which takes no parameters. So you can instatiate *FactorialCalculator* and then call its *factoral*-Method.